# JSで日付によって画像の角度を変える

Tags: javascript, html, css

ホロスコープ作成サイトを作っています。
jsを使って現在の日付けを取得し、その日付に応じて画像の角度を変更したいのですが、初心者のため、試行錯誤もできていません。具体性がなく非常に答えにくいとは思うのですが方法を教えてください。

Comment: 日付の取得なら「javascript 　日時」、画像の回転であれば「javascript  画像 　回転」で調べてみて、調べた中での不明点を質問に追加されてはどうでしょうか? その方が回答を得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: user20098さん　ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//日付けを取得
const date = new Date();
const image = document.querySelector("img");

//日付けから必要な情報を抜き出す
const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const day = date.getDate();

//年月日から角度を算出
const angle = (year + month + day) % 360;

//JavaScriptでスタイルを変更することで画像の角度を変更
image.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
```